Springboot Database JDBC URL [Connecting through datasource 'HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)']
I am learning Springboot and wanted to make an application that lets me use postgres to make simple APIs. I have been trying to establish the connection to the JDBC to be able to create a table, however it will not show me a successful connection. I don't know if this is part of the problem but I downloaded postgres through postgres.app on mac.
This is the logging that I am receiving:
Database JDBC URL [Connecting through datasource 'HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)']
    Database driver: undefined/unknown
    Database version: 17.2
    Autocommit mode: undefined/unknown
    Isolation level: undefined/unknown
    Minimum pool size: undefined/unknown
    Maximum pool size: undefined/unknown

My Applications.properties file
spring.application.name=amigoscode-demo
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/student
spring.datasource.username=becky
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.dll-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl = true

My pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>amigoscode-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>amigoscode-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot Using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SGDpanrc8U&amp;t=424s</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.7.4</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Based on the youtube tutorial I should see this in my console when the application starts
Things I have tried/other information:

My postgres server does not currently have a password and I have checked that I can access it without one.
I have tried adding properties such as these, but they have not changed anything:

   spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
   spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
   spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=30000
   spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=600000
   spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1800000


I have verified there is a connection with mvn dependency:tree and it shows a connection
I have verified that the local host is accepting connections with: pg_isready -d postgresql://localhost:5432/student


I thought you should add the postgres driver name in the application.properties file.
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
I Hope this helps!!
